# SQL Case for 2 values lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am trying to use a Case statement to look up a table, if the table shows a Stage 06 and a Stage 11 then this is considered Amended if only a Stage 06 is shown then this is not Amended.

My current code is:

```
DECLARE

@DATE1 DATETIME = '04/01/2017',
@DATE2 DATETIME = '04/30/2017',
@RAISEDBY VARCHAR (10) = 'CAROLIND'

SELECT DISTINCT

J.[RAISED-BY],
J.[JOB-NO],
J.[JOB-STATUS],
J.[DATE-LOGGED],
J.[CURRENT-STAGE-CODE],
J.[ORIG-LOGGED-VALUE] AS "LOGGED-VALUE",
J.[TOTAL-VALUE],
J.[SHORT-DESCRIPTION],
J.[CONTRACTOR],
C.[DESCRIPTION],
CASE 
    WHEN SH.[STAGE-CODE] = '06' AND SH.[STAGE-CODE] = '11' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
    END AS "AMENDED"

FROM

DBO.[JOB] AS J
LEFT OUTER JOIN
DBO.[CONT] as C ON C.CONTRACTOR = J.CONTRACTOR
LEFT OUTER JOIN
DBO.[JOB-STAGE-HISTORY] AS SH ON SH.[JOB-NO] = J.[JOB-NO]

WHERE

J.[DATE-LOGGED] BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE2
AND
J.[RAISED-BY] = @RAISEDBY
AND
SH.[JOB-NO] = 'W0423540'

ORDER BY

J.[RAISED-BY],
J.[JOB-NO]
```

This query is currently returning a 'NO' when it be 'YES' as there is a row for 06 and 11 in the Job Stage History table.

Thanks

**Query Results**

### [image]

**Job Stage History Table**

### [image]

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement. (It returns a value.)

Comment: Are you looking for the value of the row to be 06 as well as 11? It will select by row. Do you mean OR?

Comment: If 06 and 11 exist this should return a single row with Amended = Yes, if only 06 exists then return a single row with Amended = No

Comment: I would suggest (1) simplify the query and the question; (2) provide sample data and desired results in the question.

Comment: @TheWeblord2000 It will be better if you include desired result in your question.

Comment: On the query results screenshot above, the desired result is one row with Amended showing as Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` is checking if a single field in a record is equal to two different values, which is always false.  What you want is to check if there exists two different rows in the `JOB-STAGE-HISTORY` table (an **06** row, and an **11** row).  Try replacing the `CASE` with this:

```
case when (select count(distinct j.[STAGE-CODE]) 
           from [JOB-STAGE-HISTORY] j 
           where j.[JOB-NO] = sh.[JOB-NO] 
           and j.[STAGE-CODE] in ('06','11')) = 2 
then 'YES' else 'NO' end AMENDED
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether the below will fetch you the result.

Modify/add join conditions as below.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
DBO.[JOB-STAGE-HISTORY] AS SH ON SH.[JOB-NO] = J.[JOB-NO]
and sh.[STAGE-CODE] = 06

left outer join
dbo.[JOB-STAGE-HISTORY] AS SH1 on SH1.[JOB-NO] = SH.[JOB-NO]
and SH1.[STAGE-CODE] = 11
```

after adding the join conditions change the case statement as below.

```
CASE 
    WHEN SH1.[STAGE-CODE] is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end.
```

The answer is based on the assumption made on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers provided worked great, thanks to both involved.  I spent a bit further time looking at this challenge and believe this could be another way to resolve:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

J.[RAISED-BY],
J.[JOB-NO],
J.[JOB-STATUS],
J.[DATE-LOGGED],
J.[CURRENT-STAGE-CODE],
J.[ORIG-LOGGED-VALUE] AS "LOGGED-VALUE",
J.[TOTAL-VALUE],
J.[SHORT-DESCRIPTION],
J.[CONTRACTOR],
C.[DESCRIPTION],
SH.[JOB-AMENDED]

FROM

DBO.[JOB] AS J
LEFT OUTER JOIN
DBO.[CONT] as C ON C.CONTRACTOR = J.CONTRACTOR
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT 
       [JOB-NO], 
       CASE WHEN MAX([STAGE-CODE]) = ('11') THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS "JOB-AMENDED"
FROM
DBO.[JOB-STAGE-HISTORY] 
WHERE [STAGE-CODE] IN ('06','11')
GROUP BY [JOB-NO]) AS SH ON J.[JOB-NO] = SH.[JOB-NO] 

WHERE

J.[DATE-LOGGED] BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE2
AND
J.[RAISED-BY] = @RAISEDBY
```

It certainly gives the required result as well as the other answers provided.

Comment: Are you sure this works?  It seems like it would give "YES" even if there was no "06" record.

Comment: Yes as on our data "Yes" only actually requires a "Stage 11" so by doing the Max to find if this exists out of (6/11) then it returns a "Yes" if the Max is only 6 then this is a "No"